# How to integrate Gerrit(Open/Merged/Abandoned) status with Jira?

Tags: jira, gerrit

One of our Gerrit project need to be integrated with Jira, So that we would want to track our Gerrit code review requests such as `(Open/Merged/Abandoned)` status automatically in Jira itself.

So it is possible using `its-jira` gerrit plugin? (Or) We need to install `Gerrit plugin in Jira` and configure the same?  Couldn't find a document. Can someone share the helpful document? it will be great helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Jira Server you just need to install the [Gerrit Code Review for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210874/gerrit-code-review-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) plugin and start "tagging" your changes with the Jira-Id in the commit message or in the change topic.

See more info in the plugin page or in the documentation [here](https://github.com/MeetMe/jira-gerrit-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot Marcelo for quick support. i will check this.